# iptables ip/domain blocking is not working when I connect device using shotspot

Tags: iptables

I am using below iptables rules to block domain like (facebook.com)
these are working fine on my internet.
iptables -N mychain;
iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j mychain;
iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j mychain;
iptables -A mychain-d [www.facebook.com](http://www.facebook.com) -j DROP

but when connecting the ubuntu device with hotspot then these rules are not working.
Please suggest, what changes i need to do make it working with hotspot.

Comment: `iptables` is **IP driven** not **hostname driven**.  It's likely that Facebook's loadbalance/GeoIP systems serve a different geolocated IP from the DNS lookups on your hotspot than on your Ubuntu device.  You need a system to do filtration at the DNS level - that gets a lot more complicated.  I have such a system in place, wholly DNS driven, but it's *painful* to set up so I've been hesitant to share...

Comment: Please suggest any way to tackle case where network is of type hotspot.

Comment: if you want to block access to specific domains, `iptables` is not the way to go unfortunately, because of geoip, etc. and different load balancers.  Let me dig into some things first and get back to you on a solution.